# call variable inside a function

Tags: javascript

I have a function something like this:

```
var func1 = function () {
       var apple;
       //Some other code
};
```

and I have passed the function as a parameter for some other function

```
control(func);
```

Now, I want to access the variable apple in the control function. `func1.apple` doesn't work. Does anyone have an idea how this is do-able?

Comment: I think you can only do this if you add return apple statement to your paramfunction. if this is not how you want you should use an object literal as parameter and not a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s not really possible using that sort of syntax without changing the function. `func1.apple` doesn’t run `apple`, and something like `func1().apple` would have already run `apple`. If you just want to return something, then do so using `return`:

```
var func1 = function() {
    var apple;
    …
    return apple;
};

var apple = func1();
```

Or return an object if you have several values to return:

```
var func1 = function() {
    var apple;
    …
    return {apple: apple};
};

var apple = func1().apple;
```

If you need the value *during* the function’s run, the only* way to accomplish this is to use another callback within your callback:

```
var func1 = function(useApple) {
    var apple;
    …
    useApple(apple);
    …
};

func1(function(apple) {
    // Do something with apple
});
```

* Properties are another way, but they count as callbacks and are evil :)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you may be looking for is the constructor pattern

```
var func1 = function () {
       this.apple = "My Apple";
};

var myFuncInstance = new func1();

myFuncInstance.apple; // "My Apple"
```